# Ionic 2 - DateTime - Add additional button

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic2

I want to add a button to the DateTime component as one of the following suggestions:

[Button above DateTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRaAV.png)

[Button in DateTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNSzl.png)

I tried to get the DOM Element of DateTime and add a button this way, but i didn't get it.

Has someone an advice?